# Recieving and processing array of data on STM32

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, dma, nucleo

I am trying to use RealTerm to send a .txt file containing a 10X10 array of data to my STM32 NUCLEO board using an UART.

So far I have been using HAL_UART_Receive_DMA and I have been able to store simple lines of data in a 1-D buffer, but I would like to store the data as an array I can then perform some operations on. Do I need to receive the data as one long buffer and then make an array (if so how) or can I receive an array directly?

Comment: Perhaps you will need to implement a communication protocol. Or you can use some already made, i.e modbus is very widely used, also there are some MATLAB targets,...etc.

Comment: DMA adds a lot of complexity and doesn't really offer any benefit unless you go do something else useful in the meantime.  You likely need to define some sort of format, either human style (commas and newlines) machine style, for example see the format of "hex files".  Whatever you do, look for something explicit, do not depend on time.  And try to keep things in terms of *printable characters* - the hassles of going to a binary format (vs blocks encoded in printable hex) are typically not worth the roughly 2.1 times efficiency difference unless you are really pushing speed limits.

Comment: Thats not the only reason for DMA some DMA solutions cant run in parallel (in general not necessarily cortex-ms), on mcus like this DMA is generally for priority and timing, if you need to keep a buffer full or empty you would want to use DMA rather than polling or interrupts.

Comment: you would want to put a frame around it, something that allows you to find the start of packet/data and length checksum and/or end of packet, etc.  And then extract the payload from there.  A 2D array in memory is really just linear memory anyway, so is there really any parsing that has to happen?

Comment: I don't get it. what is the difference between 1-D (I assume "dimension") buffer and an array? Isn't one just describing a functional and another physical aspect of the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

First off, read about [semihosting](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0471/g/Bgbjjgij).

> Semihosting is a mechanism that enables code running on an ARM target
> to communicate and use the Input/Output facilities on a host computer
> that is running a debugger.
>
> Examples of these facilities include keyboard input, screen output,
> and disk I/O. For example, you can use this mechanism to enable
> functions in the C library, such as printf() and scanf(), to use the
> screen and keyboard of the host instead of having a screen and
> keyboard on the target system.

In addition to printf and scanf, it allows you to use file IO standard libraries. you can use this to import your computer files without UART/DMA hassle.

---

To answer that specific question, it's completely up to you to format and use it. one way would be pointers. you have a 10x10 array (a matrix!) and you get one array of 100 elements. now define a pointer to first element, another one to 10th element and so on. Example for 20 elements with pointers to element 0 and element 10:

```
int recieved_arr[20] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19};
int *(new_arr[2]);

int main()
{
    new_arr[0] = &recieved_arr[0];
    new_arr[1] = &recieved_arr[10];
    printf("2nd element of the 1st new array : %d\r\n", new_arr[0][1]);
    printf("5th element of the 1st new array : %d\r\n", new_arr[0][4]);
    printf("1st element of the 2nd new array : %d\r\n", new_arr[1][0]);
    return 0;
}
//the output would be:
2nd element of the 1st new array : 1
5th element of the 1st new array : 4
1st element of the 2nd new array : 10
```

Then you can use the that pointers they way you would use 2D arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You state that you can already process a single line.

Then just need to change your destination pointer to the next line of the array then receive another line.

Continue performing the above until all lines of the array are received

Answer (score 0):

The receiving DMA buffer should not be used to process the data directly...even if you transfer the data out to another DMA buffer (I could be misinterpreting this, but just to make sure I'm pointing it out). Regardless, another buffer will be needed since the receiving DMA buffer should/could continue to receive data (you didn't describe your application or the size of the DMA buffer, but normally that would be the case). As user3629249 stated, if you can already process a single line then repeat the process until all your lines have been read from the DMA buffer into your array buffer (incrementing positions as needed). Once the array buffer is filled (I assume your data stream has end markers of some sort), then you can set a flag to process the array. Without the additional details I'll assume you know how to create memory array's or even single chunks of memory, but referenced as an array (like in display screen buffers). So all of that is left out of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I have been using HAL_UART_Receive_DMA and I have been able to store simple lines of data

If you were able to receive any data using DMA then you pretty much done with the hardest part. Because there is nothing else out there. UART does not receive "lines" or "data", it receives bytes. Well, unless you change frame length, which is really bad idea anyway.

There are three design decisions you have to make when dealing with UART.

1. Does your program need to do something else while waiting for data?

If not, then using DMA or interrupts is pretty much pointless, a simple blocking read will do. If yes, then you have several methods to choose from. You can use basic UART interrupt to receive data byte-by-byte and collect them in buffer by yourself. You can use HAL with interrupt or DMA to read either entire file or chunks   of it (again, combining them in target array by yourself). In latter case you also have an option to use circular buffer to save some memory, however this is only useful if you can process incoming data on the fly, not if you want to collect it all first before processing.

2. How big is your data and do you know the size in advance?

".txt file containing a 10X10 array of data" does not tell much. 10 of what? Characters? Numbers? Words? Does this include CR/LF at the end of the lines?
You need to figure this out because in the end it defines whether or not you can fit  entire file in memory, and how suitable DMA is for the task.

Because there is one catch with DMA - you either need to know the exact data size in advance, or you have to handle IDLE interrupt or RTO event to pull out the remaining bytes out of circular buffer.

An alternative is to read byte by byte and look for predefined EOF byte, but this is more suitable for binary communication than for text file upload.

3. Perhaps most important (and related to #2 above), what is the data encoding?

I believe while dumping file into port RealTerm does not really care about file content. But for you on receiving end it matters a lot. For example, binary 10x10 file will be exactly 100 bytes long, and that is what you will receive. The same 100 bytes in hexadecimal format with 2-byte EOL separation will be 220 bytes long, and you also have to convert character pairs into actual bytes after reception. CSV file with 100 bytes in decimal format can be anywhere between 220 and 420 bytes long.

In my experience, it is always better to upload reasonably small data in human *readable* and *editable* format, despite memory overhead and some decoding required.